# Meteor: How do I run the documentation server and my app at the same time, if both run their own mongodb instance on the same port?

Tags: meteor

I'm trying to run the meteor documentation server and my app at the same time, but I can only run one at a time, out of the box. They both run their own instance of mongodb and so the ports colide...

Comment: You can run each application on a different port with `meteor run --port 4000`, but this will probably not allow for more mongodb instances.

Answer (score 2):

When launching either your app or the documentation meteor app, do:

meteor --port [anything but 3000 or 3001]

Running with the default settings will take ports 3000 and 3001 as well as another higher port for mongod. You shouldn't get mongod ports clashing if you use different values for --port when starting the meteor app (including the documentation server, which is just another meteor app).

Comment: That works for the server but not for the Mongo Database server. It's the mongo database server, as I have mentioned in the question, that is causing the problem. Nice try though ;)

Comment: I've just updated my answer to point out that there should be no port clashing for the two mongod instances that you'll be running if you have the documentation server (which is a meteor app) as well as your other app running, with the --port given with different values to each (no --port given is the same as --port 3000). Certainly when I tried this myself this is what I observed. If your experience is not the same, could you explain more about the symptoms you see.